# Printer on OS X not printing across VPN subnets

Tags: linux, vpn, mac-osx, openvpn, linux-networking

I have an interesting situation where I have a two servers that connect two subnets via a VPN.  One side is 192.168.0.0/24 and the other is 192.168.1.0/24.  Communications appear to be working okay. I can ping fqdn's on each side (each side's gateway server has a DNS server integrated (SME Server)) as well as the IP's of any devices at either location.

I have a Dell C2665 at each location; they work okay onsite and even Windows from remote locations are able to print to each remote location, however when I set this same printer up on OS X workstations, it seems to drop into null.  The printer is detected at setup when I pass it the IP or hostname, but then when I print a test page, it is never seemingly received by the remote receiving printer.

Also, I can share a remote printer from a local Windows machine and the OS X machine can print through that.  Obviously this is something unique to CUPS or OSX's communication with the printer, but I can't put my finger on it.

I have tried a variety of things here, but it would seem that something outside of what I'm seeing is happening just in the OS X / CUPS print subsystem scenario (even though it even get's status info and other data back properly from the remote printer).  Any thoughts on how to dig deeper and find out where / why this failure is occurring?

Comment: Pause the printer in question on the print server. Then print to it from the affected machine. If the print job arrives in the paused print queue on the print server then I think you can focus your efforts on the print server.

Comment: @joeqwerty well I have actually done that.  The jobs never arrive to the print server proper.

Comment: Try using `lpstat -v` to see how the Mac is trying to connect to the printer. If it has a `dnssd://<something>.local` url, it's trying to use multicast DNS to locate the printer, and that may not be getting forwarded across the VPN.